# Error android.content.ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-intent

i'm getting error

`android.content.ActivityNotFoundException`

detailed

`No activity found to handle Intent{com.alpha.beta.SQLVIEW}`

even though in my manifest file i have :

```
<activity

android:name=".SQLView"

android:label="@string/title_activity_app" >

<action android:name="com.alpha.beta.SQLVIEW" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

</activity>
```

plus my intent looks like:

```
Intent mi = new Intent("com.alpha.beta.SQLVIEW");

startActivity(mi);
```

Comment: what is package name in manifest file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name used in the intent **SQLVIEW** is different from the one in the manifest **SQLView**..

in the intent:

```
Intent mi = new Intent("com.alpha.beta.SQLVIEW");
```

in the manifest:

```
 android:name=".SQLView"
```

They should be the same, you can also use the intent this way..

```
Intent mi = new Intent(this, SQLView.class);

startActivity(mi);
```

Comment: so you say to change either of them to match same?

Comment: yep easy to change Intent mi = new Intent("com.alpha.beta.SQLView");

Comment: @Aditya, yes, the class name in the intent and the class name is case sensitive so it has to match.

Answer (score 1):

start new activity as:

```
Intent mi = new Intent(Current_Activity.this,SQLView.class);

startActivity(mi);
```